# No route matches [GET] on a post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I started Ruby on Rails few days ago, and I'm struggling with routing.

Indeed, I would like to make a post request through my routes.rb, but I keep having a

> No route matches [GET] "/orders/refresh"

error.

Here is my routes.rb :

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  get '/orders', to: 'orders#index'
  get '/orders/active(/:q)', to: 'orders#active'
  post '/orders/refresh', to: 'orders#refresh'
end
```

and here is my controller (orders_controller.rb) :

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @orders = Order.order(:departure_date).all
    render json: @orders.to_json
  end

  def active
    if !params[:q]
      @orders = Order.order(:departure_date).where(active: true)
    else
      @orders = Order.order(:departure_date).where("reference = ? OR client_name = ? OR departure_city = ? OR arrival_city = ?",
        params[:q], params[:q], params[:q], params[:q])
        .where(active: true)
    end
    render json: @orders.to_json
  end

  def refresh
    response = RestClient.get 'https://wakeo-technical-test.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/api.json'
    json = JSON.parse response

    if !json.nil?
      json.each do |order|
        old_order = Order.find_by(reference: order["client_number"])
        if !old_order.nil?
          old_order.update(departure_date: order["dep_time"])
          old_order.update(arrival_date: order["arr_time"])
          old_order.update(client_name: order["company"])
          old_order.update(departure_city: order["dep_city"])
          old_order.update(arrival_city: order["arr_city"])
        end
      end
    else
      puts "error seeding external API"
    end
  end
end
```

From what I have understood, it seems like RoR will try to find a GET request for that specific URL, and since it won't find any, it will throw that error. How could I make that request be a POST for Rails ?

Also, I would appreciate any suggestion about how I should use ActiveRecord Querying, I'm pretty sure I could do it better here.

Thanks, have a great day !

EDIT : Here is the list of different routes my app seems to be capable of, including my POST.

[Routes and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvLVu.png)

Comment: Your routes seem declared correctly, but your app *receives* a get request when it should be a post request. Is there any template code with a link to that route?

Comment: How do you generate the link to `/orders/refresh` in your view? Please show our view.

Comment: @weltschmerz nope, that's the problem, I found some solutions with templating but I'm only using Model, Controller and routes.

Comment: @spickermann same answer as weltschmerz, I'm not using any views. Should I ?

Comment: How do you hit the `/orders/refresh` if not in your browser? Do you call it with a client via API? Did you tell the client to use `POST` instead of `GET`?

Comment: @spickermann I do hit it in my browser, and then I watch the result on my console where the server is running. Now you mention it, this might be a bit wild...

Comment: Are you using Rails UJS helpers like `link_to 'Refresh', '/orders/refresh' method: :post`? In that case you probably have a javascript error thats preventing Rails UJS from doing its job or haven't included it in your assets. This is an extremely common newbie problem in Rails that require a bit of debugging to solve. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#data-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common reason you unexpectly get `GET` requests instead of `PUT`, `PATCH`, `POST` or `DELETE` is that you are using `link_to 'Something', '/some_path', method: :post` and you broke the Rails Unobtrusive Javascript Driver (Rails UJS):

> Because submitting forms with HTTP methods other than GET and POST
> isn't widely supported across browsers, all other HTTP methods are
> actually sent over POST with the intended method indicated in the
> _method parameter. Rails automatically detects and compensates for this.

Rails does that with a JavaScript event handler attached to any link with the `data-method` attribute. But if you broke that functionality the browser will just perform its default action which is sending a GET request when the user clicks a link.

This problem usually boils down to one or more of:

- Your javascript is throwing an error which halts script execution (use the browser console to find the error, make it suck less).
- Rails UJS is not included in your assets pipeline or webpacker packs and thus not in the page.

The quick and easy solution to sidestep the problem is by using [`button_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) which actually creates a form and does not require any JavaScript trickery. After all forms can send POST requests. And by just passing a `_METHOD` hidden field Rack will treat the request as any other HTTP verb.

```
button_to 'Something', '/some_path', method: :post
```

But in the long run you should probably fix the problem if you want to use any of the features of Rails UJS.

Answer (score 0):

Your routes.rb is expecting a POST request to /orders/refresh routes, but apparently you are testing with a GET request.

Try changing your routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   # ...
   get '/orders/refresh', to: 'orders#refresh'
end
```

... or change your request to a POST request. If you are using Rails forms, you must do something like this:

```
form_with(url: "/orders/refresh", method: "post")
```

Comment: I'm doing that small API for an exercise, and I have to make that request a POST. Could I do that without a view ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I figured it out.

It might be because when I hit /orders/refresh directly in my web browser, it will try to find a GET corresponding to the request.

I managed to make POST using a client like Postman, and everything works fine.

Thank you for your help !